# Alternative for running Python script from shell using existing virtual environment

Tags: python, windows, shell, command-prompt

Normally when I want to run a script from the command prompt or shell I navigate to the directory my script file is in and type `python <name script>.py` and press Enter

```
D:\TestPython>python run.py
here a demo run
```

However at the moment a script I want to run relies an a package in the virtual environment. In the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) I found a way to solve this relying on the execution of an activate.bat file:

```
D:\TestPython>C:\Users\elmex\VENV\Scripts\activate.bat 
(VENV) D:\TestPython>python run.py
here a demo run
```

Now I wonder if there is an alternative to this, something like `D:\TestPython>python use all packages form virt env this <dir> run.py`.

Comment: For your first example, if your system is configured properly you can add `D:\TestPython` to the `PATH` environment variable and `.PY` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable. Then you can execute `run` from any working directory. The shell will find "run.py", get the associated command template (e.g. `py.exe "%1" %*`), expand the template, and execute the command.

Comment: For running a script in a virtual environment, install Python 3 to get the py.exe launcher as the default association for .py files. Then in run.py add a shebang with the fully-qualified path to that interpreter, e.g. `#!C:\Users\elmex\VENV\Scripts\python.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

so sorry @Elmex80s there are no way for that in the other way yes I meant from inside a virtualenv you can access to the packages installed in you global system but before install this virtual env you need to use the option system-site-packages and you would have the access I talking about it. You can see all this here:https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption--system-site-packages
Regards